# Using qmake as qmake -project

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I want to make a GUI application using Qt and am not able to get started. I wrote the following code in my editor:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWidget window;
    window.resize(250,150);
    window.setWindowTitle("Simple example");
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Then I make a `project.pro` file in my current directory with the following content:

```
SOURCES = qt.cpp
HEADERS = QApplication QWidget
CONFIG += qt warn_on release
```

Then I type in terminal, `qmake -project` but the terminal does nothing. Even the command prompt doesn't appear. It just sits idle as if waiting for something, like the following:

```
user@user:~$ qmake -project
_
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: Try to remove `HEADERS` from the project file (you don't have header files) and call `qmake project.pro` instead.

Comment: Notice that 'qmake -project' will create the .pro file using files in directory. Then just do 'qmake' and finally 'make'. Take a look to [doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-running.html)

Comment: @vahancho: yes that works, but got another error - 
`bison -d bison1.y
bison1.y:24.14-17: error: symbol TERM is used, but is not defined as a token and has no rules
make: *** [all] Error 1`
after doing qmake(which works) and make

Comment: @user2436425, you need to add `TEMPLATE = app` and `TARGET = my_qt_app_name` to the project file, I think.

Comment: @vahancho: same error persists after adding those both, in place of `my_qt_app_name`, I wrote `qt` as my source file is `qt.cpp`;

    [project.pro](http://pastebin.com/siXG691k);
    [compilation in terminal](http://pastebin.com/NnCH2jwm)

Comment: @user2436425, the problem seems to be not in qmake or project file. I have no idea what `bison` related stuff comes from.

Comment: @vahancho: well, since I am stuck in this QT, I am thinking of rather using Java's `Swing` library. I basically want my (simple)application to be portable, so I think both of these suffice ,however, Swing seems to be considerably easier. No extra packages need to be installed after it and also compiling it is same as `java app` rather than use something like qmake.. so just to ask what's your opinion on it?

Comment: @user2436425, I hardly can have an objective opinion on your decision. Although Qt and Swing use different programming languages, both are supposed to create multiplatform applications, so your choice does probably make sense, if using Java is much easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

The following line creates a project source file for you.

> >  qmake -project

The only thing in this case you need is .cpp & .h files for your project.

Now, remove your project source file you've created. In the directory, you need only .cpp & .h for your project (in your case there is only qt.cpp). Now, go to the terminal and type

> > qmake -project -o myproject.pro

This line created a project source file for you and its name is "myproject".

Type (assuming there is only one project source file)

> >  qmake

The above line created the Makefile.

Now, type

> >  make

The output (by default in mac) has the extension .app and its name is myproject.app. Now to run it (in mac).

> >  open myproject.app

As you see, you don't have full control over your project. To overcome this problem, you need to create your own project source file ( which I prefer that).